# Response is either empty object or Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 from Nodejs

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, redux-thunk

I'm testing with some fake JSON file in a single-page app, but I always get **Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0**, or **empty object** if I use JSON.stringify() on my promise return. I'm not sure why this is happening, and I have been struggling with this for two days. Am I missing something?

My file structure is like:

```
-server
 -client
  -action
   -movies.js
 -route
  -fakeData.json
  -movieList.js
 -index.js
```

When I use POSTMAN, I can see the return object, and when I inspect the browser in network tab, I can see the request, and it return status(200). I'm doing this with Redux-thunk, as well http-proxy-middleware library for them to talk

fakeData.json::

```
{
    "movies": [
        {
            "name": "test1",
            "url": "https://example1.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "test2",
            "url": "https://example2.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

movieList.js:

```
const characters = require('../FakeData/characters.json');

// reads the file synchronously
var fs = require("fs");

module.exports = (app) => {
    app.get('/api/characters', (req, res) => {

        const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/characters.json', 'utf8')

        try {
            const data = JSON.parse(fileContents)
            res.json({data})
        } catch(err) {
            console.error(err)
        }
        // res.json(characters)
    });
}
```

index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

require('./routes/movieList')(app);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    // Express will server up production assets like main.css or main.js
    app.use(express.static('client/build'));

    const path = require('path');
    // Express serves up index.html if it doesn't recognize the route
    app.get('/', (req, res) => { // Catch the rest
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));

    });
}

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT)
```

movies.js:

```
export const FETCH_CHAR = "fetch_character";
export const SET_CHARS = "set_characters";

function handleResponse(response) {
    if(response.ok) {
        return response.json()
    } else {
        let error = new Error(response.statusText);
        error.response = response;
        throw error;
    }
}

export function setMovies(characters) {
    return {
        type: SET_CHARS,
        characters
    }
}

export function fetchChars() {
    return dispatch => {
        fetch('/api/characters')
        .then(res => {
            // return res.text()  **When I try res.text(), I got html response
            return res.json()    **This gives me Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
        })
        .then(data => dispatch(setMovies(data.characters)))
    }
}
```

This is what I set up proxy in my React if you are curious:

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(proxy('/api/*', { target: 'http://localhost:5000' , changeOrigin: true }));
};
```

What I'm thinking is that after I get the data from the fake JSON file, then I can do more action on it like showing the movies data because I'm call this API call right after the code hook up the DOM.

**Edit**
In my movieList.js, I tried to use:

```
try {
    const data = JSON.parse(fileContents)
    res.json({ foo: data })
} catch(err) {
    console.error(err)
}
```

and in movies.js, I try to return res instead of res.json() because I will get  Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0, and in my network tab of dev tool for response, I get the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of  in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <style>
      html {
          height: 100%;
          min-height: 100%;
          position: relative;
          /* height: 100vh; */
          margin: 0;
          /* overflow:auto; */
      }
      body {
          height: 100%;
          position: relative;
      }
      #root {
          height: 100%;
          /* height: 100vh; */
      }
    </style>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  <script src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script><script src="/static/js/1.chunk.js"></script><script src="/static/js/main.chunk.js"></script><script src="/main.8c1de248b2f13e929d84.hot-update.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the content/body of the response in the network tab of the browser dev tools? This is most likely a CORS issue. If the server is returning an HTML error page, JSON.parse() will fail.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I just test it out with cors library with res.json(), and I still get Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 error

Comment: Can you try changing res.json({data}) to res.json({foo:data}). I know it sounds weird. Also please confirm the network tab has content type of application/json for this request.

Comment: Yes, I just did. But still the same error

Comment: Please paste the contents of the response into the question from the network tab

Comment: I did, please review. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the brackets in your response.

```
.then(response =>  response.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
```

Comment: I put brackets in there just trying to see debugger, so I don't think that's the problem

Comment: you also have a return there which is not needed, get the response use .json() on it, then do something with the data..

Comment: Right. I understand, but that's not the issue... Any other ideas??

Comment: what happens when you console log data?

Comment: I always got Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at the response.json()

Comment: Yes, but still. And when I look at the response in network tab, I always got the HTML like in my edited post above. I don't know what happened

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194652/discussion-between-tim-and-johnny88520).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create the mock data from the server why dont create a variable that is the json and export it?

The problem that is happening, based in my experience, is that you are sending a string and the client is expecting a JSON.

Try something like:

fakeData.js:

```
const fake = {
"movies": [
    {
        "name": "test1",
        "url": "https://example1.com"
    },
    {
        "name": "test2",
        "url": "https://example2.com"
    }
   ]
  }

module.exports = fake
```

And in movieList.js:

```
const characters = require('./whatever-path/fakeData.js');

module.exports = (app) => {
    app.get('/api/characters', (req, res) => {
       res.json({characters})
    });
}
```

Hope it works!